# How can I configure access token in doorkeeper-gem on Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

## doorkeeper's spec with token through http header

My goal is creating secure API between iOS and Rails4. So I've been trying doorkeeper-gem for a while. But I'm wasting time for testing and configuration now. In detail, the problem is `doorkeeper_for` method and token transferring through HTTP header. How using http request parameter  was successful, but sending token through parameter is not good. So I want to send token with HTTP header, but doorkeeper does not see where `request.header["My_TOKEN_PLACE"]`.

---

### Circumstance

Now, I have `api_controller.rb`, `communities_controller.rb`, `communities_controller_spec.rb`, `doorkeeper.rb`.

`api_controller.rb`

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  before_action :create_token
  doorkeeper_for :all, scopes: [:app]
  respond_to :json, handler: :jbuilder

  private

  def error_handle
    raise 'Failed.'
  end

  def create_token
    params[:access_token] = request.headers["HTTP_AUTHENTICATION"]
    # this does not read by doorkeeper
  end
end
```

---

and `communities_controller.rb`

```
class CommunitiesController < ApiController
  def show
    @community = Community.find params[:id]
  end

  def search
    Query.create q: @search_form.q if @search_form.q.present?
    community_search = Community.search title_or_description_cont: @search_form.q
    @communities = community_search.result(distinct: true).page params[:page]
  end
end
```

---

and `communities_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CommunitiesController do
  let!(:application) { Doorkeeper::Application.create!(name: "MyApp", redirect_uri: "http://app.com") }
  let(:user){ create :user }
  let!(:access_token) { Doorkeeper::AccessToken.create! application_id: application.id, resource_owner_id: user.id, scopes: "app" }

  before(:each) do
    request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
  end

  describe "#show" do
    let(:community) { create :community }

    before do
      request.headers["HTTP_AUTHENTICATION"] = access_token.token
      get :show, id: community
    end

    it { expect(response).to be_success }
    it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
  end

  describe "#search" do
    before { get :search, access_token: access_token.token }

    it { expect(response).to be_success }
    it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }
  end
end
```

---

and `config/initializer/doorkeeper.rb`

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_authenticator do
    User.find id: session[:user_id]

  default_scopes :app
end
```

---

and result of `rspec communities_controller.rb` is here.

```
/Users/shogochiai/Documents/anyll% be rspec spec/controllers/communities_controller_spec.rb
FF..

Failures:

  1) CommunitiesController#show should be success
     Failure/Error: it { expect(response).to be_success }
       expected success? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/communities_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top(required)>'

  2) CommunitiesController#show should equal 200
     Failure/Error: it { expect(response.status).to be 200 }

       expected #<Fixnum:401> => 200
            got #<Fixnum:803> => 401

       Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
       but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
       `expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
       object identity in this example.
     # ./spec/controllers/communities_controller_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top(required)>'

Finished in 0.33439 seconds
4 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/communities_controller_spec.rb:20 # CommunitiesController#show should be success
rspec ./spec/controllers/communities_controller_spec.rb:21 # CommunitiesController#show should equal 200

Randomized with seed 18521
```

---

It seems

```
before do
  request.headers["HTTP_AUTHENTICATION"] = access_token.token
  get :show, id: community
end
```

is not authenticated

and

`before { get :search, access_token: access_token.token }`

is authenticated.

### Supplementary

I did `pp` debug in controller, `pp request` and `pp responce` result had have a pair of key-value that `"HTTP_AUTHENTICATION": "xrfui24j53iji34.....(some Hash value)"`.